# Querying JSONB having array elements in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table named `settings` with the columns `program_id(number), client_id(number), filters(Jsonb)` and filters column has jsonb data in such format-

```
{
  "sources": [
    {
      "conditions": [
        {
          "value": [
            {
              "id": 1211,
              "name": "ABM BETA INVITE LIST",
              "isSelected": true
            }
          ],
          "condition": "one of the following"
        }
      ],
      "objectType": "SmartLists",
      "subscriptionId": 1173,
      "integrationType": "mkto"
    }
  ],
  "listType": "All Accounts",
  "programId": 30203,
  "noOfAccounts": null,
  "expiryDuration": 0,
  "subscriptionId": null,
  "updateFrequency": null
}
```

I now want to retrieve all the records from table **settings** where `filters.sources[0].integrationType = 'mkto'`. I have tried this query but gives me error of set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE-

```
select * from settings where (jsonb_array_elements(filters -> 'sources') ->> 'integrationType' = 'mkto');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I now want to retrieve all the records from table settings where `filters.sources[0].integrationType = 'mkto'`.

Using the [`#>>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   settings
WHERE  filters #>> '{sources, 0, integrationType}' = 'mkto';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QWrDwdop)

`filters #>> '{sources, 0, integrationType}'` is the same as:

```
filters -> 'sources' -> 0 ->> 'integrationType'
filters['sources'][0]['integrationType'] #>> '{}'  -- for Postgres 14+
```

But do you really only want to look at the first array element?

Comment: Yes @Erwin, I only want to look at the first array element always. Thanks a lot this query worked like a charm.

Comment: Hey @Erwin Brandstetter, could you also please help me with the update query for the same if I want to update the `integrationType` to **pdto** from **mkto** for such records.

Comment: @Srk95: Go ahead and post a question if you can't find an answer on SO.

Comment: Alternatively: with a JSON path expression: `where filters @@ '$.sources[0].integrationType == "mkto"'`